# How to copy specific columns from a csv into redshift table using lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-redshift

I am trying to load a csv file ins s3 into redshift using aws copy command in lambda. The problem is i have more columns in csv than in redshift table. 
so whenever i trigger lambda fnction i get the error "Extra columns found"

how to load specific columns from csv

my csv files is of form

year, month, description, category,SKU, sales(month)

and my redshift table is of form

```
year month description category SKU
-----------------------------------
```

my copy command is as follows

```
COPY public.sales 
FROM 's3://mybucket/sales.csv' 
iam_role 'arn:aws:iam::99999999999:role/RedShiftRole' 
delimiter ',' 
ignoreheader 1 
acceptinvchars
```

Answer (score 1):

You can specify the list of columns to import into your table - see [`COPY` command documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_COPY.html#r_COPY-syntax) for more details.

```
COPY public.sales (year, month, description, category, SKU)
FROM 's3://mybucket/sales.csv' 
iam_role 'arn:aws:iam::99999999999:role/RedShiftRole' 
delimiter ',' 
ignoreheader 1 
acceptinvchars
```

Comment: yes, you can say: please populate only these columns in table. But you can't specify: please take only these columns from file.
I would suggest to see if it is possible using JSONPaths File:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/copy-parameters-data-format.html#copy-json-jsonpaths

Comment: I thought you were `COPY`ing a csv file? Can you show an example of your data file?